# open outlook window to send email asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, email, outlook

I am writing a project in asp.net C# using Visual Studio 2010.
I want to write function, which opens outlook window to send email when user clicks a button.

I tried this:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Outlook.Application oApp    = new Outlook.Application ();
Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem ( Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem );
oMailItem.To    = address;
// body, bcc etc...
oMailItem.Display ( true );
```

But compiler says there is no namespace Office inside namespace Microsoft. 
Actually Microsoft Office including Outlook fully installed in my computer.

Should I include Office library to Visual Studio?
How the problem can be solved?

Comment: Are you trying to open outlook from a webpage ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`, Outlook must be installed on the server (and runs on the server, not on user computer).

Have you tried using [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        using (m)
        {
            //sender is set in web.config:   <smtp from="my alias &lt;mymail@mysite.com&gt;">
            m.To.Add(to);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
                m.CC.Add(cc);
            m.Subject = subject;
            m.Body = body;
            m.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentName))
                m.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentFile, attachmentName));

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            try
            { client.Send(m); }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException) {/*errors can happen*/ }
        }
```

Comment: At the moment I am running the project in localhost, so my computer is not a server?  I tried smtp, but I want to open Outlook as I said above

Comment: Yes, actually your computer is the server; remember that you must install outlook on the server where the application will be deployed.

Comment: How in this case user can see the outlook window running on the server?

Comment: The user cannot see the outlook window running on the server.  If you want the user to see the email that's been created then you don't want to run Outlook on the server; you should use a `mailto:` link on your page to invoke the user's email client.

Comment: So there is no any way to run outlook window to send email in client computer?

Comment: No, `mailto:` works but opens just an empty mail with user's default mail software.

Answer (score 3):

this use outlook to send email with recipient, subject, and body preloaded.

```
<A HREF="mailto:recipient@domain.com?subject=this is the subject&body=Hi, This is the message body">send outlook email</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather you try like this,add using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; reference

```
        Application app = new Application();
        NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("mapi");
        ns.Logon("Email-Id", "Password", false, true);
        MailItem message = (MailItem)app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        message.To = "To-Email_ID";
        message.Subject = "A simple test message";
        message.Body = "This is a test. It should work";

        message.Attachments.Add(@"File_Path", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        message.Send();
        ns.Logoff();
```